# How to Check which validation is violated for a model in Yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

when I print ths statement inside a model as,

```
Yii::error($this->validate());
```

it gives me

```
false
```

***QUESTION*** :

How can I check which validation is getting violated? As I have 38 parameters with different rules, I am tired debugging application. any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the errors for your model this way:

```
$this->getErrors();
```

Reference:

- [Class yii\base\Model->getErrors() documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#getErrors()-detail)

Comment: Thanks! I will try and let you know.